# Grails Project - Open dialog box

Tags: html, grails, extjs

In my application, when I hit Run button which is scripted in gsp page as:

```
<input type="button" value="Run" onClick="submitJob()"></input>
```

submitJob() function is defined in a ExtJs JavaScript file which does some operations and calls the controller code which renders a different gsp output page as:

```
render(template: "/plugin/jobPlot_out", model:[jobName:jobName], contextPath:pluginContextPath)
```

In my application in web browser it displays the output in the same web page. How to display the same output in a dialog box and not in the same page?

Answer (score 0):

I am new to JavaScript so I posted this question. What I did:
I had to search for the div id of the Run button and had to search for the URL where the div id gets loaded. Upon finding this, I had to write a jQUERY code to open a dialog box and the resulting output was rendered there.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not pretty sure I got you right but have you tried to use a **redirect** instruction?

http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/3.0.x/ref/Controllers/redirect.html

Comment: I am sorry I read the documentation but I dint understand what it does. My goal would be to show my output in a dialog box instead of on the same web page.

Comment: In your code try to use redirect and then call your dialog box showing method. 
It works well for me with 'flash.message' but have never tried with dialog boxes.